# How to use make_heap to create a min heap in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, heap

How do I create a a min heap using the `make_heap` method in `<algorithm>`

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) it says, we can pass in a third argument **Compare comp** that is a

> Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments,
>   and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates
>   whether the element passed as first argument is considered to be less
>   than the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines. The
>   function shall not modify any of its arguments. This can either be a
>   function pointer or a function object.

So I tried passing in a *function object* as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct myComp {

    bool operator() (const pair<int, char>& lhs, const pair<int, char>& rhs) {
        return lhs.first > rhs.first;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector< pair<int, char> > Q;
    Q.push_back( pair<int, char>(10, 'c') );
    Q.push_back( pair<int, char>(123, 'a') );
    Q.push_back( pair<int, char>(2, 'd') );
    Q.push_back( pair<int, char>(9, 'f') );
    Q.push_back( pair<int, char>(81, 'b') );
    Q.push_back( pair<int, char>(4, 'e') );

    make_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end(), myComp);

    pop_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());

    cout << Q.back().first << ", " << Q.back().second << endl;
    Q.pop_back();

    return 0;
}
```

and I am getting this following error

```
jdoodle.cpp: In function 'int main()':
jdoodle.cpp:25:38: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  make_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end(), myComp);
                                      ^
```

I don't really understand what this means, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myComp` is a type name, while `std::make_heap` is a function (template), and to call it you need to pass an *object*. So create an object of that type.

```
make_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end(), myComp{});
```

The `{}` will initialize the `myComp` object that you pass.

When you read the documentation `Compare` is the deduced type of the functor, but note that the function template expects a `comp` *function parameter*, that's your object.